# How to close/remove menu item or tab when right click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm creating tab using multiview and what I want to do is to close one of the menu tabs when I right click on it.

These are part of the aspx and code behind:

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Menu
    id="Menu1"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab"
    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selectedTab"
    CssClass="tabs" width = "100%" 
    OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"                           
    Runat="server" style=" text-align:center;">
</asp:Menu>
<div id="divcont" runat="server" class="tabContents" style="height:100%; width:100%;" visible="false">
    <asp:MultiView
        id="MultiView1"
        ActiveViewIndex="0"
        Runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="v1" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f1" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>      
        <asp:View ID="v2" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f2" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v3" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f3" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v4" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f4" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v5" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f5" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v6" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f6" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>        
        <asp:View ID="v7" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f7" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v8" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f8" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v9" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f9" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v10" runat="server" >
        <iframe id="f10" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

(This is part of the NodeChanged event)

```
...
...
...
int TabCount = Convert.ToInt32(lblTabCounter.Text.ToString());
int TabIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblTabCounterIndex.Text.ToString());

if(TabCount <= 10)
    {
        divcont.Visible = true;
        string tabName = getURLName(uRL);
        MenuItem myItem = new MenuItem(tabName, TabIndex.ToString());
        Menu1.Items.AddAt(TabIndex, myItem);
        f1.Attributes.Add("src", lblURL.Text.ToString());
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = TabIndex;
        TabCount++;
        TabIndex++;
        lblTabCounter.Text = TabCount.ToString();
        lblTabCounterIndex.Text = TabIndex.ToString();
        tvPermissions.ExpandAll();

        int i = ctr;
    }
```

(This is for the MenuItemClick Event)

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = index; 
}
```

This is the sample output:

[image]

The treeview is located in the orange part(left). While the blue one that is the target url that is located in the project. Based from the codes that I provided it will only point out to one frame named "f1" as an example though there are 10 of them. How can I remove a particular tab (say tab "Expenses") when I right click on it?

I want this to be done in the code behind. For javascript/jquery solutions please provide its code behind implementation or how to call/use it from code behind.

Please help me with this. For clarifications please leave a comment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different approach. Instead of right click I use double click with confirmation to remove the tab.

I also adapted the user defined JS libraries to catch the double click and add more effects.

I mentioned as well that I already have my JavaScript function to work on this I'm just looking for alternatives other than JavaScript or JQuery. However I'm surprised that I didn't get any response or comments.

Thank you for reading this post.