# How to execute/call oncontextmenu in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to call oncontextmenu event from call behind?

For example:

```
<asp:label id="label1" runat="server" text="My label" oncontextmenu="label1_oncontextmenu"></asp:label>
```

Please help me with this. I can do this in javascript and jquery but I want to do it in pure asp.net or c# code behind.

Thank you!

Comment: And if you could do something server-side, what would you do? You couldn't display something on the client. What would a server-side method do for you?

Comment: I'm going to use this to close a tab when right click. I have a related post here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16955676/2427387. But unfortunately I'm not getting any response or answers.

Comment: Just call the `label1_oncontextmenu` method.  But that's not going to work on a right-click.

Comment: I just did that but nothng happens.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4495626.  What you want is not possible in code- behind.